# Can't upload sketch after overheating

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, uploading

I'm using an Arduino nano, after an unfortunate event, The mega chip heat up and when I tried touching it, it burned my finger. After that, I connected to my laptop's USB port and the computer recognized it. But after I hit the upload button, the RX light flash 3 times and stop, no Loader light and it just stop there, and the IDE says this:

```
Arduino: 1.8.19 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

Sketch uses 2806 bytes (9%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.

variables use 44 bytes (2%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2004 bytes for local variables. 
Maximum is 2048 bytes.

An error occurred while uploading the sketch

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x84

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x84

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x84

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x84

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x84

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x84

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x84

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x84

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x84

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x84



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Any advice?

Comment: Get a new one? It's possible the USB bridge survived, but the actual MCU did not.

Comment: *"Any advice?¨* I'm not sure what you're going to find as acceptable advice.So, you may want to make that clear. As is the advice is something like: buy a new board..

Comment: make an assumption that the issue is just a coincidence and do all necessary troubleshooting ... only it all fails, declare the device to be dead

Comment: Right, getta new one then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you did but you probably either overvoltage it or connected it backwards. The odds are extremely high you fried the mega chip. Good news, it is not a total waste, you learned something not to do. It is still good for practicing troubleshooting, if you find what failed great or if you cannot fix it,  you will have learned something useful. Atthis point use it for practicing SMD soldering. In the end remove the parts and use the PCB for a template. The recommended solution is to purchase two more, that way if one fails the wate time will be shorter.

Comment: Yea, It might be because when I plug it into the board, the Arduino is reversed and d10/d12 is plugged to 5v/gnd instead of gnd and vcc. Or maybe I moved it back a pin so the rst/gnd is plugged to the 5v/gnd. I honestly can't be sure about it as how panicked I was back then.